# how to manage 2 dropdowns in the same activity in Android Studio (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, dropdown, android-adapterview

I have a project using 2 dropdowns.
First one is for Buildings
The second is for apartment number inside building.
So when we select A building and  apartment number, we get the Owner name.

I have created lists in strings.xml

```
<!--    LIST buildings-->
<string-array name="list_buildings">
    <item>Building 1</item>
    <item>Building 3</item>
    <item>Building 3</item>
</string-array>

<!--    LIST Houses-->
<string-array name="list_houses">
    <item>House 1</item>
    <item>House 2</item>
    <item>House 3</item>
</string-array>
```

I have tried this in MainActivity.kt

```
// buildings
    // list in strings.xml
    val buildings = resources.getStringArray(R.array.list_buidings)
    val buldingAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
        this,
        R.layout.dropdown_buildings, 
        buildings
    )  

    // Houses

    val houses = resources.getStringArray(R.array.list_houses)

    val houseAdapter = ArrayAdapter(
        this,
        R.layout.dropdown_llamadas,
        houses
    )

       
        // ▼ id from AutoCompleteTextViews 
          // in activity_main.xml

    with(binding.chooseBuilding) {
        setAdapter(arrayAdapter)

        onItemClickListener = this@MainActivity
    }

    /
    with(binding.chooseHouse) {
        setAdapter(houseAdapter)
        // LISTENERS
        onItemClickListener = this@MainActivity

    }
}

override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

    val item = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

// this is to test if dropdowns are working. OK
// the problem is I can´t separate both dropdowns 

Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

 // I get error trying to change the "item" element to customize the logic. 


if ( (item == "Building 1") || (item == "House 2" )  && (binding.chooseBuilding.isSelected)) {

binding.myTextView.text = "Katerine lives here..."

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the problem then ? You should put your issue in a mannered way . There are many ways of implementing two drop down menus , whats your need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are using Spinner then you should use `onItemSelectedListener` instead of `onItemClickListener`

```
onItemSelectedListener = this@MainActivity
```

Second, you can separate both dropdowns simply by using the `parent` variable from the override function like this:

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {

     var building = ""
     var houses = ""

     if (parent == binding.chooseBuilding) {
            building = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
     } else if (parent == binding.chooseHouse) {
            houses = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
     }

     if ((building == "Building 1") || (houses == "House 2") && (binding.chooseBuilding.isSelected)) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Katerine lives here...")
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am working on it

Comment: @Reichlich if you need any help just mention me